# Purpose of equity listing?

Tags: equities, exchange

I have a simple question on US stock market: what is the purpose of listing a stock to a specific exchange given that it can be traded on multiple exchanges?

For example, apple stock (AAPL) is listed on NASDAQ, but according to https://chartexchange.com/symbol/nasdaq-aapl/exchange-volume/, it is also traded on NYSE Arca, CBOE, and many more.
If this is the case, what motivates a company to pay listing fee to an exchange?
Does NASDAQ hold any exclusive right to trade AAPL?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The short answer would be, that's how the market is structured. Initially, they have to select one exchange (primary market) based on regulatory requirement, listing process and fees, target investors, trading volume and liquidity. Once they get listed in let's say NASDAQ, they can further go through more processes and do dual listing (or any other secondary market). Exchange provides a lot of services for the listed companies (facilitate trading, regulatory compliance processes etc.) for which they charge the companies. Exchange does not "hold exclusive right" to trade any stocks.